# How to add module template on theme template

Tags: magento2.2

Please check the picture below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Template from Magento theme will override all the same templates from modules. So, if you have some template in your theme, you must make changes in theme's templates.

Otherwise remove template from custom from theme and override it in your module. Sequence of modules is important here if you override template that already defined